# Returning all nodes in the tree in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which lists companies, and a table that links these companies together to form an ownership hierarchy:

dbo.Suppliers:

- Id
- Name

dbo.SupplierLinks:

- SupplierId
- ParentId

I'd like to create a stored procedure (or function?), that accepts a supplier Id, and returns rows of all linked (either directly or indirectly) suppliers.

Of course, this doesn't return indirectly linked suppliers:

```
DECLARE @SupplierId int
SET @SupplierId = 5

SELECT * 
FROM Config.SupplierLinks sl
WHERE sl.ParentId = @SupplierId
OR sl.SupplierId = @SupplierId
```

How can I accomplish this?

Example:

```
Supplier 1
   |
  / \
2    3
     |
    /\
   5  4
```

Data:

```
Id      ParentId        Name

4       3               'Supplier 4'
5       3               'Supplier 5'
3       1               'Supplier 3'
2       1               'Supplier 2'
```

*Note: Supplier 1, the top-level parent, does not exist in the link table above.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Use/look for CTE (recursive) to create your hierarchy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive Query using CTE in SQL Server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003895/recursive-query-using-cte-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
;WITH Parents
AS
(
    Select SP1.SupplierId , SP1.ParentId from SupplierLinks SP1 where SP1.SupplierId = @SupplierId
    Union All
    Select SP2.SupplierId , SP2.ParentId
    From SupplierLinks SP2 Inner Join Parents C on C.ParentId = SP2.SupplierId
)

Decalare @ParentId int
Select @ParentId = P.SupplierId
From Parents as P
Where parentid = 0 or ParentId is null

;WITH Children
AS
(
    Select SP1 .SupplierId , SP1 .ParentId from SupplierLinks SP1 where SupplierId = @ParentId
    Union All
    Select SP2.SupplierId , SP2.ParentId
    From SupplierLinks SP2 Inner Join Children C on C.SupplierId = SP2.parentid
)
```

Comment: This works well, thanks. However, it doesn't seem to return records of suppliers linked to SP1? (going down the tree, in other words). Do I need to add another Union All? I'm still trying to figure out to construct the query...

Comment: may be you need to get parent and then find children records. Try updated answer